# Fetch dataframe for nested XML schema

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to read a XML with a custom schema into a dataframe but unable to fetch the values.

I tried tweaking around with the rowTag and rootTag but nothing works.

This is the schema I'm using:

```
val input = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("dnum", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("dtype", StringType, true),
      StructField("dname", StringType, true),
      StructField("dloc", StringType, true)))

  val bookschema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("cost", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("details", ArrayType(input, true),
      true),
    StructField("name", StringType, true),
    StructField("num", LongType, true)))

  val bookdataschema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("count", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("lang", StringType, true)))

  val schema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("bookdata", bookdataschema, true),
    StructField("book", bookschema, true)))
```

This is how the file is being read:

```
sqc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "books")
      .schema(schema)
      .load(filePath)
```

Sample xml:

```
<books>
    <bookdata>
        <count>4</count>
        <lang>English</lang>
    </bookdata>
    <book>
        <num>11</num>
        <name>A</name>
        <cost>200.00</cost>
        <details>
            <dnum>1</dnum>
            <dtype>X</dtype>
        </details>
        <details>
            <dnum>5</dnum>
            <dtype>A</dtype>
        </details>
    </book>
    <book>
        <num>12</num>
        <name>B</name>
        <cost>300.00</cost>
        <details>
            <dnum>2</dnum>
            <dtype>Y</dtype>

        </details>
    </book>
</books>
```

Ive to go about joining some additional columns inside the details tag of individual book. But how to read the current data in a dataframe so that it has all the rows for the entries. When I try to read it with "books" as rowTag it only returns 1 row in the dataframe with the bookdata value and the last book value.

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
|bookdata   |book                                      |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
|[4,English]|[300.0,WrappedArray([2,Y,null,null]),B,12]|
+-----------+------------------------------------------+
```

I just care about the book tag details at this point because I need to append some nested tags inside details, but the final output file must have the bookdata data as well while writing the DF to XML. How should I work this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can load 2 dataframes: one containing your `book` data, and one your `bookdata`:

```scala
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "books")
      .option("rowTag", "book")
      .schema(bookschema)
      .load(filePath)

df.show()
/*
df has the books data:
+-----+--------------------+----+---+
| cost|             details|name|num|
+-----+--------------------+----+---+
|200.0|[[1, X,,], [5, A,,]]|   A| 11|
|300.0|          [[2, Y,,]]|   B| 12|
+-----+--------------------+----+---+
*/

val df2 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rootTag", "books")
      .option("rowTag", "bookdata")
      .schema(bookdataschema)
      .load(filePath)

df2.show()
/*
df2 has the bookdata data:
+-----+-------+
|count|   lang|
+-----+-------+
|    4|English|
+-----+-------+
*/
```